# How to make a get request to retrieve the latest document of an index in the elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, npm, elasticsearch-5

I am developing a node.js application to get the latest value of an index from an elastic cluster. My logstash server pipes data to elasticsearch every second. So, the elasticsearch index gets updated every second. Every second a new document is added to the elasticsearch index.

Here is a sample JSON document

```
{
  "_index": "weather",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "eMIs_mQBol0Vk4cfUzG5",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "weather": {
      "main": "Clouds",
      "icon": "04n",
      "description": "broken clouds",
      "id": 803
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "clouds": {
      "all": 75
    },
    "main": {
      "humidity": 36,
      "pressure": 1022,
      "temp": 41,
      "temp_max": 26,
      "temp_min": 26
    },
    "wind": {
      "deg": 360,
      "speed": 3.6
    },
    "visibility": 16093,
    "@timestamp": "2018-08-03T05:04:35.134Z",
    "name": "Santa Clara"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-08-03T05:04:35.134Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1533272675134
  ]
}
```

Here is the picture of the table,

[image]
My node.js code looks like this,

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

let client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: ['http://localhost:9200']
});

client.ping({
    requestTimeout: 30000,
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('Everything is ok');
    }
});

async function getResponse() {
    const response = await client.get({
        index: 'weather',
        type: 'doc',
        id: 'KsHW_GQBol0Vk4cfl2WY'
    });
    console.log(response);
}

getResponse();
```

I am able to retrieve the JSON document based on the id of the index. But, I want to retrieve the latest JSON document. How can I configure my server to read the latest document every second from the server? Is there a way to retrieve the latest JSON document(without knowing the id in advance)?

Can someone please help me with this? I would really appreciate if you could help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a **timestamp** field in your index and that is updated/added after every document is indexed. Then you can simply perform a **sort** on timestamp field with **size=1**.

The below query will give you the most recent value:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure of the syntax of node.js but something like this would work:

```
client.search({
  index: 'weather',
  type: 'doc'
  body: {
    sort: [{ "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }],
    size: 1,
    query: { match_all: {}}
 }
});
```

Based on your mapping you've **@timestamp** so you should use:

```
client.search({
  index: 'weather',
  type: 'doc'
  body: {
    sort: [{ "@timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }],
    size: 1,
    query: { match_all: {}}
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you said.

But, I get the following error,

(node:50308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [illegal_argument_exception] [field_sort] unknown field [ignore_unmapped], parser not found

This is my code,

const response = await client.search({
        index: 'weather',
        type: 'doc',
        body: {
            sort: [{ "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }],
            size: 1,
            query: { match_all: {} }
        }
    });

Comment: Please post the index mapping.

Comment: Sure, I have edited my question. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Updated my answer.